# Check if nodes are off the screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a node on my screen that is moved with the gyroscope. But I can't limit it's position to the screen, I have tried this, but it only worked for the bottom and the the top:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval){

     ...

     if sprite.position.x <= sprite.frame.width / 2 {
          print("out on the left of the screen")
     }
     if sprite.position.x >= self.frame.width - sprite.frame.width / 2 {
          print("out on the right of the screen")
     }
     if sprite.position.y <= sprite.frame.height / 2 {
          print("out on the top of the screen")
          //worked
     }
     if sprite.position.y <= self.frame.height - sprite.frame.height / 2 {
          print("out on the bottom of the screen")
          //worked
     }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to check whether a node is offscreen? Or limit it to stay onscreen?

Comment: limit it to stay onscreen

Comment: print sprite.position.x and sprite.position.y before if statment to see what is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to stop the sprite going off screen I'd recommend you use Sprite Kit's physics engine.

Firstly, add an [`SKPhysicsBody`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithRectangleOfSize:) to your sprite, for example:

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
```

Secondly, you need to add a physics body to the scene, for example:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: view.bounds)
}
```

Finally, since you want gravity disabled you can either disable it just for `sprite`:

```
sprite.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
// force unwrapping here is okay because we're SURE sprite has a physics body.
```

or, disable gravity for everything in the scene:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zeroVector
// self in this case is your `SKScene` subclass.
```

For more information [The Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH1-SW1) is really useful, in the case of physics see the [Simulating Physics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html) section.

Comment: the node weirdly starts falling from the screen and bugging it all when there's a physicsBody

Comment: Ahh okay, you'll want to disable gravity. I've updated my answer :)

Comment: ok, right, it worked perfectly. But then it created another issue. Is there a way to prevent another node from colliding with the screen node?

Comment: Have a look at [The Sprite Kit Programming Guide: Simulating Physics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html), the section titled 'Working with Collisions and Contacts' for that particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval){

 ...

 if sprite.position.x <= 0 {
      print("out on the left of the screen")
 }
 if sprite.position.x >= self.size.width {
      print("out on the right of the screen")
 }
 if sprite.position.y <= sprite.frame.height / 2 {
      print("out on the top of the screen")
      //worked
 }
 if sprite.position.y <= self.frame.height - sprite.frame.height / 2 {
      print("out on the bottom of the screen")
      //worked
 }
```

}

To detect if the sprite went off the screen to the left, you compare the sprites  x coordinate to `x=0` and to see if the sprite went off the screen to the right you compare with the size of the scene width.

Comment: My post is just to detect when the sprite went off the screen. Not stop it from going off screen.

Comment: yeah, I know. But it didn't detect when the sprite went off the screen

Answer (score 1):

```
 guard let position = spaceMan?.position else { return }
print(position)
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
if abs(position.x) > screenWidth/2 { // off the horizontal axis
  spaceMan?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}
if abs(position.y) > screenHeight/2 { // off the vertical axis
  spaceMan?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}
```